# How to get ContentPresenter in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I have the code below under **Themes\Generic.xaml**

Now I need to get ***cPresenter*** in code behind how I can do it?

In fact I try to convert Silverlight implementation into WPF code.
And I want to use something like Silverlight has:

```
FrameworkElement cp = this.GetTemplateChild("cPresenter") as FrameworkElement;
```

**Themes\Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="local:Marquee">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Marquee">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">    
                        <ScrollViewer Width="Auto" Height="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                            <Canvas>
                                <ContentPresenter  x:Name="cPresenter" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>                            
                            </Canvas>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason that shouldn't work in WPF also.
Put this in your code for `Marquee`.

```
private ContentPresenter cPresenter;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
   base.OnApplyTemplate();
   this.cPresenter = this.GetTemplateChild("cPresenter") as ContentPresenter;
}
```

Comment: Special THANKS to you Steve! You've just helped me a lot! I owe you a beer, bro!